# whats the role or url_mapper in cppcms

Tags: cppcms

In the example [`url mapping`](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_url_mapping) it keeps a map of regex url pattern and its corresponding action with `dispatcher().assign()`. But  what is the job of `mapper().assign()` ? even if I comment that out it works.

In documentation it says

> we create a name for this part called "number" and we provide a URL
>   formatting pattern /number/{1} - the opposite of regular expression
>   where {1} is a placeholder for the first parameter for formatting the
>   appropriate URL.

But why create *a name for the part* and why its necessary ?

```
hello(cppcms::service &srv): cppcms::application(srv){
    dispatcher().assign("/number/(\\d+)",&hello::number,this,1);
    mapper().assign("number","/number/{1}");

    dispatcher().assign("/smile",&hello::smile,this);
    mapper().assign("smile","/smile");

    dispatcher().assign("",&hello::welcome,this);
    mapper().assign("");

    mapper().root("/hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching is the act of mapping Urls to your (C++)application-methods.

"Mappping" is the opposite of it. The mapper-object translates methods to Urls.
So this means: You define how the Urls for a certain methode have to be constructed.

The Advantage of doing this:

```
dispatcher().assign("/number/(\\d+)",&hello::number,this,1);
mapper().assign("number","/number/{1}");
```

You now can write in your template code things like this

```
<a href='<% url "number" using some_varibale %>'>Link</a>
```

"And where lies the advantage ?" you might ask.

The information how the url is constructed is defined at ONE position in your code (DRY). If for any reason the signature will change later on, you will only have to change that one line of code. (And not to search through your whole project)